# Prove $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt[3]{2}$ is irrational

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification, irrational-numbers

I solved the problem by way of contradiction. Suppose $x = \sqrt{2} + \sqrt[3]{2}$ is rational. Then we have 
$$2 = (x - \sqrt{2})^3 = x^3 - 3\sqrt{2}x^2 + 6x - 2\sqrt{2} = (x^3 + 6x) - \sqrt{2}(3x^2 - 2)$$
I've already shown that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational, and it's easy to show a rational number plus an irrational number is irrational and that the product of an irrational and a rational is irrational. Given those facts, we have $(x^3 + 6x) \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $\sqrt{2}(3x^2 - 2) \not\in \mathbb{Q}$, so 
$$2 = a\in\mathbb{Q} + b\not\in\mathbb{Q} \implies 2 \not\in\mathbb{Q}$$ a contradiction.

However, the book does it differently: it says

> Show that $x$ satisfies an equation of the type  $$x^6 + a_1x^5 +
>  \ldots + a_6 = 0$$ where $a_1,\ldots,a_6$ are integers; prove that $x$
>   is then either irrational or an integer.

1. Is my way correct as well?
2. I don't understand how the book does it. How does one obtain that equation, and once obtained, how does it prove $x$ is irrational?

Comment: For 2. start with $x-\sqrt 2 =\root 3 \of 2$, then cube both sides. Proceed in the obvious manner to obtain your polynomial. Use the [Rational Roots theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) at the end.

Comment: I did cube both sides, but it only gives you a 3rd order polynomial. The book says to use a 6th order.

Comment: You should be able to rewrite it with only a product of a square root with a polynomial on one one side.and a polynomial on the other Square both sides.

Comment: Oh, I see, ya that part is easy. Once you point out the rational roots theorem the proof is obvious. Still, is my method correct?

Comment: Your reasoning looks perfectly valid. You show clearly that if $x$ is rational then $\sqrt{2}$ must also be rational.

Comment: The proof has a gap: the argument fails if $\,3x^2-2 =0.\ $ Do you see how to fix that?

Comment: @BillDubuque Simplest way: $x^2 = 2 + 2\sqrt{2}\sqrt[3]{2} + \sqrt[3]{4}$ is irrational since I've already proven $\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{4}\not\in\mathbb{Q}$. Then we have an irrational minus a rational, which is irrational, and zero is rational.

Comment: @Keith If $x$ is rational, obviously the first one is rational, just plug in $x=\frac{p}{q}$ and work it out, you get another fraction of the form $\frac{ap}{bq}$. As for the second one, prove that the product of a rational and an irrational is irrational. Proof by contradiction: assume the sum is rational. Then if $s$ is irrational, then $s\frac{p}{q} = \frac{p'}{q'}$. Then $s = \frac{p'q}{q'p}$, so $s$ is rational, a contradiction.

Comment: Maybe simpler to note $x^2>1$?

Comment: $3x^2 >3\cdot1>2\Rightarrow 3x^2-2>0$.

Comment: Oh, I see now, ya that's a lot better.

Comment: @RenéG There is also a sign error: $\,3x^2-2\,$ should be $\,3x^2+2,\,$ which is simpler to prove $\neq 0\ $

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've done half the job for their way: from 
$$2 = (x - \sqrt{2})^3 = x^3 - 3\sqrt{2}x^2 + 6x - 2\sqrt{2} = (x^3 + 6x) - \sqrt{2}(3x^2 - 2)$$
you deduce:$$(x^3 + 6x-2)^2=2(3x^2+2)^2,$$
whence $$x^6-6x^4-4x^3+12x^2-24x-4=0.$$
By the *Rational roots* theorem, we know that a rational root has to be an integer, and a divisor of $4$, i. e. it can be only $\pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 4$. Just test them to check none is a root.

Answer (score 2):

1. Yes.
2. It is a more general way. We look for an equation written up by integers that $x$ satisfies. The first steps are the same: to arrive to the degree 6 polynomial, put the member with $\sqrt2$ to one side and all the others to the other side in your final equation, and square to get integer coeffiecients. 
   If a solution was rational, it would be integer because of the lead coefficient and would divide $a_6$.

> Square $\sqrt2\,(3x^2-2)=x^3+6x-2$.

Comment: Your first claim is incorrect - see my comment to the question.

Comment: Hey, I didn't know that you can hide things here! Thanks for the hint.

Comment: @BillDubuque But once it's shown that $3x^2 - 2 \neq 0$, the proof is correct?

Comment: @RenéG Yes, since then we infer $\,\sqrt2 = (x^3\!+6x-2)/(3x^2\!-2)\in\Bbb Q,\,$ contradiction.

Comment: @BillDubuque yes indeed, you are right, $3x^2-2$ is missing.

Comment: @Berci There is another error too: $\ 3x^2-2\,$ should be $\,3x^2+2\,$ (which is easier to prove $\neq 0)\quad$